# The new SSIS in SQL2005/SQL2008 are oversized

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I studied the new MERGE Statement and there is a nice example for importing a flatfile.

```
INSERT <Table>
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET BULK <Import-Flat-File>, <Format-File>...
```

seems to be a good replacment for such a simple job and avoids to build a SSIS-Package.

```
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL bcp <Table or View> out <Flat-File> ...
```

is almost simpler than building an SSIS, isn't it? 
The old style DTS fitted better for this small jobs.

(I know that the MERGE-Statement doesn't run on a SQL2005)

Do you think that scripting is the best approach for such 'easy things'? Or schould i go deeper into SSIS doing simple import/export's?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. That said, This question is better suited for StackOverflow. Please don't crosspost the post, the question will be automatically migrated to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having xp_CmdShell active on a SQL machine is considered a security risk, so I'd avoid that if possible.

I'd do this in SSIS if it were me - It will be a few minutes more work, but you get the ability to version control via source control so the logic of the task is backed up, you'll also get error-handling so you can decide how to handle the error when it inevitably goes wrong.

Also you'll get better with SSIS, no harm practising with minor tasks :)